# Asp.net mvc sitemap link to external site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to add to MvcSiteMap link to external site , but link doesn't rendered by Menu Helper.

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1" controller="#" Action="#" Url="#" ">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1"    Url="/Site1"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte2"   Url="/Site2" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte3"   Url="/Site3" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1_CH"   Url="/Site1_CH" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Logout"   Url="/RedirectToLogin.aspx" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What am I Missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by the # sign in controller, action and url? These cannot be resolved to existing controller

Comment: Yes , I know , but I dont have a real controller , All these nodes are links to External websites , I hope this provider supports such links right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4.0 now supports external URLs and to the best of my knowledge this worked in version 3.x as well.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Somewhere" url="http://www.somewhere.com/"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

The root node has to be resolvable to a controller and action, otherwise the menu will never been shown, also it makes no sense to set Url="#" on the root node, as this is autogenerated from you route to the controller and action.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1" controller="Home" Action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1"    Url="/Site1"/>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte2"   Url="/Site2" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte3"   Url="/Site3" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="SIte1_CH"   Url="/Site1_CH" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Logout"   Url="/RedirectToLogin.aspx" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

On the child nodes you should be able to use the URL attribute.